# Magento 1.9: Show my Additional Information Details into Short Description Section

Tags: magento-1.9, additional-information

My additional information :

> app\design\frontend\default\theme327k\template\catalog\product\view\attrubutes.phtml

```
<div class="box-collateral-content">
    <table class="data-table" id="product-attribute-specs-table">
        <col width="25%" />
        <col />
        <tbody>
            <?php foreach ($_additional as $_data): ?>
                <tr>
                    <th class="label"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->__($_data['label'])) ?></th>
                    <td class="data"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']) ?></td>
                </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <script type="text/javascript">decorateTable('product-attribute-specs-table')</script>
</div>
```

I want to add my additional information into my short description section :

> app\design\frontend\default\theme327k\template\catalog\product\view.phtml

Comment: Do you want to remove the additional information tab and add data in the short description section?

Comment: No, display in both section

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add Additional Information section in by adding below code of line in your `app\design\frontend\default\theme327k\template\catalog\product\view.phtml` after the short description section.

```
echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/product_view_attributes')->setTemplate('catalog/product/view/attributes.phtml')->toHtml();
```

**Hope it helps!!!**

Comment: Normally we overwrite core files like copy core files and put into app/code/local/mage then put here core files and do some changes, same how to over write design files?

Comment: you can put these files in your theme for example, you need to add the view.phtml file under below path /app/design/frontend/[Vendor]/[Theme]/template/catalog/product/view.phtml

Comment: Already files available in same location what you mentioned above, C:\wamp64\www\magepro\app\design\frontend\default\theme327k\template\catalog\product

Comment: I want to know which location move my core design files and edit without affect original version?

Comment: This is not a core file, theme327k is your custom theme in which you've made your changes. Magento has provided, Rwd, Base and default theme as core themes.

Comment: If short description not available additional information also not showing, how to show my additional information even products don't have short description?

Comment: Find $_product->getShortDescription() in your view.phtml file and add your code after the short description block.

Comment: How to remove https://snipboard.io/PhNBU1.jpg    Additional Information heading

Comment: You can hide it with CSS or you need to define different file for your requirements defined in the block for example catalog/product/view/attributes-short-desc.phtml

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98841/discussion-between-zus-and-sumit).